# How can I dynamically create a new instance of an object in Java?

Tags: java

I have a class called `GetInput.java`
and I have a class called `GetNotReleasedInput.java`.
I extend `GetInput` in `GetNotReleasedInput`.
In `GetInput`, I call a private function called `addLineToArray()`
and in that function I define a new class which contains details about the import.

However since I'm creating a generic class(`GetInput`) for *all* input files,
I cannot say in `addLineToArray()`:

```
AAData nextData = new AAData();
```

because I have AA / Not Released, and in this case it should be NotReleased.
So how can I dynamically make that new `nextData` in that function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either you make a protected method for creating the `nextData` object so that subclasses can decide how to do the manufacturing, or you have some kind of factory object (configurable at outer object creation time) that you delegate that to. The simplest way of doing the latter is to pass in a `Class` and call its `newInstance()` method, but there's a *lot* more complexity possible; a book on software patterns will go into quite a lot of depth on this.

But if you can just delegate the whole thing to the subclass of `GetInput` then that is easiest. (You don't provide enough information for me to be able to work out which pattern you should actually use.)

Comment: I moved the method like you said and then it worked.
I also changed the original method to abstract.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you might want a virtual [factory method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern) into which you can place your object creation. In `addLineToArray()`, you then call 
your virtual `createLineObject()` instead of `new AAData()`.

However, exactly what way to go depends on a number of factors: does the kind of data created depend on the `GetInput` class, or is that a separate decision (your `GetInput` classes may vary on behaviour, whereas the data may vary by format)? Are all data related (e.g. inherits from `AAData`)?

You should add more details on what you are trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

Java doesn't allow to modify metadata at runtime by default. You can write your own classloader with a [asm](http://asm.ow2.org/) and modify the bytecode at class loading time but that's probably not what you will want.

Instead, I suggest that all your classes data classes implement `Iterable` or something like that so you can easily join then and iterate over all lines without knowing the actual type.